# Hooking subwindows && Hooking WM_APP specific private message

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, hook

I am working in a hooking app to capture some specifics events on an external app.

The first I am interested in, is detect when the main window create subwindows.
Another event I am interested in, is when the subwindow use a custom message which is refered by Spy++ as `WM_APP+2`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfcWu.png

To achieve this I coded a DLL which use `SetWindowsHookEx` with an `WH_CBT` hook to detect when a new window is created and once its created, call again `SetWindowsHookEx` again with a differente type of hook to try to catch the custom message.

First:
Is it correct to build the application like this? (creating a new hook inside the processing of an old one)

```
if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND){

        hWnd = (HWND)wParam;
        CBT_CREATEWND* cbtWnd = (CBT_CREATEWND*)lParam;

        if (_tcscmp(cbtWnd->lpcs->lpszClass, CLASSNAME) == 0){
            OutputDebugString(TEXT("Creating new Hook"));
            g_hNewHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, &MyCallWndProc, g_hMod,
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, NULL));
        }
    }
```

I guess I should create an array of `HHOOK` in the shared memory region of the DLL to call `UnhookWindowsHookEx` before my DLL would unloaded from memory, isn't it?

Secondly:
I am using `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook to try to detect `WM_APP+2` (0x8002), but aparently I am not getting the same (or similar) values of Spy++.

```
if (nCode == HC_ACTION){
    CWPSTRUCT* cwt = (CWPSTRUCT*)lParam;

    TCHAR str[100];
    _stprintf_s(str, TEXT("message: 0x%08u - wParam: 0x%08u - lParam: 0x%08u."),
        cwt->message, cwt->wParam, cwt->lParam);
    OutputDebugString(str);

}
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: So what ARE you seeing, and what does Spy++ show instead?  you have shown your code, but you have not shown your expected or actual results. Also, since you are hooking another app's window, don't assume Ansi/Unicode is being used (unless you know for sure). Use [`IsWindowUnicode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633529.aspx) to know whether a given window is using Ansi or Unicode data, and then use appropriate type-casts and functions.

Comment: Well aparently i got it, using another hook type --> "WH_GETMESSAGE". I used a wrong printf format to compare the message type i was obtaining. It wasnt %u of course but %x.

Do you know an answer to de "First:" point?
Is there any better way of "spread" the hook to Child Windows or is correct use this one?